# Python IG:Insight, KeyError: 'data' when trying to run script

Tags: python, python-3.x

first of all, I am still too new to use python, I am a web designer asked to create an Instagram insight report using python, I was given the following code. the problem is why there is always a 'data' error in this section. someone can help me?

```
    # The current API only allows the following metrics
metrics = ['email_contacts', 'follower_count', 'get_directions_clicks', 'phone_call_clicks',
           'profile_views', 'text_message_clicks', 'website_clicks', 'impressions', 'reach']

df_daily = pd.DataFrame()
for metric in metrics:
  df = pd.DataFrame(get_daily_metrics(metric))
  df = df.rename(columns={'value':metric}).set_index('end_time')
  df_daily = pd.concat([df_daily,df], axis=1)
  time.sleep(10)
```

and the result is

```
0
[{'value': 0, 'end_time': '2021-05-01T07:00:00+0000'}, {'value': 0, 'end_time': '2021-05-02T07:00:00+0000'}, {'value': 0, 'end_time': '2021-05-03T07:00:00+0000'}, {'value': 0, 'end_time': '2021-05-04T07:00:00+0000'}, {'value': 0, 'end_time': '2021-05-05T07:00:00+0000'}, {'value': 0, 'end_time': '2021-05-06T07:00:00+0000'}, {'value': 0, 'end_time': '2021-05-07T07:00:00+0000'}, {'value': 0, 'end_time': '2021-05-08T07:00:00+0000'}, {'value': 0, 'end_time': '2021-05-09T07:00:00+0000'}, {'value': 0, 'end_time': '2021-05-10T07:00:00+0000'}, {'value': 0, 'end_time': '2021-05-11T07:00:00+0000'}, {'value': 0, 'end_time': '2021-05-12T07:00:00+0000'}, {'value': 0, 'end_time': '2021-05-13T07:00:00+0000'}, {'value': 0, 'end_time': '2021-05-14T07:00:00+0000'}, {'value': 0, 'end_time': '2021-05-15T07:00:00+0000'}, {'value': 0, 'end_time': '2021-05-16T07:00:00+0000'}, {'value': 0, 'end_time': '2021-05-17T07:00:00+0000'}, {'value': 0, 'end_time': '2021-05-18T07:00:00+0000'}, {'value': 0, 'end_time': '2021-05-19T07:00:00+0000'}, {'value': 0, 'end_time': '2021-05-20T07:00:00+0000'}, {'value': 0, 'end_time': '2021-05-21T07:00:00+0000'}, {'value': 0, 'end_time': '2021-05-22T07:00:00+0000'}, {'value': 0, 'end_time': '2021-05-23T07:00:00+0000'}, {'value': 0, 'end_time': '2021-05-24T07:00:00+0000'}, {'value': 0, 'end_time': '2021-05-25T07:00:00+0000'}, {'value': 0, 'end_time': '2021-05-26T07:00:00+0000'}, {'value': 0, 'end_time': '2021-05-27T07:00:00+0000'}, {'value': 0, 'end_time': '2021-05-28T07:00:00+0000'}, {'value': 0, 'end_time': '2021-05-29T07:00:00+0000'}, {'value': 0, 'end_time': '2021-05-30T07:00:00+0000'}]
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-119-f5349fd4a2bb> in <module>()
      5 df_daily = pd.DataFrame()
      6 for metric in metrics:
----> 7   df = pd.DataFrame(get_daily_metrics(metric))
      8   df = df.rename(columns={'value':metric}).set_index('end_time')
      9   df_daily = pd.concat([df_daily,df], axis=1)

<ipython-input-116-f86765ca8e09> in get_daily_metrics(metric, period)
      8   result = []
      9   for interval in range(no_interval):
---> 10       result_temp = requests.get(URL+ig_id+'/insights?metric='+metric+'&period='+period+'&since='+str(int(start.timestamp()))+'&until='+str(int((start+datetime.timedelta(days=30)).timestamp()))+'&access_token='+token).json()['data'][0]['values']
     11       print(interval)
     12       print(result_temp)

KeyError: 'data'
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to debug the issue? 'data' means that your processing is incorrect. 'get_daily_metrics' is not defined.

Comment: I didn't debug it, may I have details about why this happened? maybe you can see all this code, I'll give the link